# Check if a value is in an array or not with Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've got some code below, that is supposed to be checking if a value is in an Array or not.

```
Sub test()
    vars1 = Array("Examples")
    vars2 = Array("Example")
    If IsInArray(Range("A1").Value, vars1) Then
        x = 1
    End If

    If IsInArray(Range("A1").Value, vars2) Then
        x = 1
    End If
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

If the cell `A1` contains the word `Examples` for some reason both of the `IsInArray` detects it as existing for both Arrays when it should only find it existing in the `vars1` array

What do I need to change to make my `IsInArray` function to make it an exact match?

Comment: Do you mean that the function IsInArray detects them when the cell A1 contains "Example"?

Answer (score 59):

You can brute force it like this:

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Use like

```
IsInArray("example", Array("example", "someother text", "more things", "and another"))
```

Comment: Is there any benefits/negatives to using your method over changing the `IsInArray` function in my original code to use `IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))` instead?

Comment: How big is your array? Is this more readable than the other methods? It might just be preference because iterating over an array is pretty quick, and (though I can't say for sure) the Match function is surely doing basically this.

Comment: I'm running 10~ arrays through `IsInArray`, in total all of them added up comes to 501 array items at the moment. It will eventually become bigger/more of them.

Comment: Those are small numbers. I'm not sure you'd see much of a difference either way. A third option is the `Dictionary` object. It has an `Exists` method and is easier to work with than arrays (no `ReDim Preserve` when adding items)

Comment: @Ryflex The biggest advantage is that it will not compare all of the elements like the other alternatives. My guess is that it can be a tiny bit slower than `Match` when the element is near the end of the array, but you can measure that with `Timer` to make sure.

Comment: @Ryflex  @Slai  it's maybe a bit late, but I wanted to clarify that using the `Match()` function is actually a lot slower than just iterating (looping) through the array. I did a test with an array of size 2000. The worst case scenario for looping through the array would be looking for the last item (at index 2000). After 5000 calls to both the `Match()` function and looping, the total time for `Match()` was `3.746094` but only `1.667969` for looping through the array. [Check the answer to this question for the code I used in my testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18769246/3023808)

Comment: the following answer has a more powerful variant of this, because it also returns the index, if found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52192798/1915920

Comment: How to use with String arrays?

Answer (score 17):

This Question was asked here: [VBA Arrays - Check strict (not approximative) match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205999/vba-arrays-check-strict-not-approximative-match)

```
Sub test()
    vars1 = Array("Examples")
    vars2 = Array("Example")
    If IsInArray(Range("A1").value, vars1) Then
        x = 1
    End If

    If IsInArray(Range("A1").value, vars2) Then
        x = 1
    End If
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: No need to loop through an array when it is done in excel, since excel have powerful match() function to do the comparison.

Comment: @Sixthsense this doesn't loop through an array

Comment: see the comment here regarding the performance issue with `Match` instead of *looping*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba#comment78852510_38268261

Answer (score 8):

I searched for this very question and when I saw the answers I ended up creating something different (because I favor less code over most other things most of the time) that should work in the vast majority of cases.  Basically turn the array into a string with array elements separated by some delimiter character, and then wrap the search value in the delimiter character and pass through instr.

```
Function is_in_array(value As String, test_array) As Boolean
    If Not (IsArray(test_array)) Then Exit Function
    If InStr(1, "'" & Join(test_array, "'") & "'", "'" & value & "'") > 0 _
        Then is_in_array = True
End Function
```

And you'd execute the function like this:

```
test = is_in_array(1, array(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Match() function in excel VBA to check whether the value exists in an array.

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Long

    vars1 = Array("Abc", "Xyz", "Examples")
    vars2 = Array("Def", "IJK", "MNO")

    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, vars1, 0)) Then
        x = 1
    ElseIf IsNumeric(Application.Match(Range("A1").Value, vars2, 0)) Then
        x = 1
    End If

    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed the `IsInArray` function to use `IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))` which resolves the problem

Comment: Not IsError() and IsNumeric() both results same answer when used with Match() function :)

Answer (score 5):

The below function returns '0' if there is no match and a 'positive integer' in case of matching:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Integer 
    IsInArray = InStr(Join(arr, ""), stringToBeFound) 
End Function
```

---

**Note**: the function first concatenates the entire array content to a string using 'Join' (not sure if the join method uses looping internally or not) and then checks for a match within this string using `InStr`.

Comment: would only works if `arr` items and `stringToBeFound` do not contain the `,` character/delimiter!

Comment: I tried it with ',' as well, but it still works! replaced 'Examples' with 'Exampl,es' in botb the arr and in stringToBeFound. Am i missing something?
BTW,  there was a typo in my code: now changed IsInArray = InStr(Join(arr, "), stringToBeFound)  to IsInArray = InStr(Join(arr, ""), stringToBeFound)

Comment: I meant "would only work ... reliably" ... `IsInArray( "ab", ("ab,c","d"))` would return `True`, but it should return `False` because none of the two array items `ab,c` nor `d` equals `ab`. Same for `IsInArray( "ab,c", ("ab","c"))`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to provide another variant that should be both **performant and powerful**, because

- it does not use the [sometimes slower `Match`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba#comment78852510_38268261))
- **supports `String`, `Integer`, `Boolean` etc.** ([not `String`-only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52192798/1915920))
- **returns the *index* of the searched-for item**
- **supports *nth-occurrence***

...

```
'-1 if not found
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327647/1915920
Public Function IsInArray( _
  item As Variant, _
  arr As Variant, _
  Optional nthOccurrence As Long = 1 _
  ) As Long

    IsInArray = -1

    Dim i As Long:  For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i) = item Then
            If nthOccurrence > 1 Then
                nthOccurrence = nthOccurrence - 1
                GoTo continue
            End If
            IsInArray = i
            Exit Function
        End If
continue:
    Next i

End Function
```

use it like this:

```
Sub testInt()
  Debug.Print IsInArray(2, Array(1, 2, 3))  '=> 1
End Sub

Sub testString1()
  Debug.Print IsInArray("b", Array("a", "b", "c", "a"))  '=> 1
End Sub

Sub testString2()
  Debug.Print IsInArray("b", Array("a", "b", "c", "b"), 2)  '=> 3
End Sub

Sub testBool1()
  Debug.Print IsInArray(False, Array(True, False, True))  '=> 1
End Sub

Sub testBool2()
  Debug.Print IsInArray(True, Array(True, False, True), 2)  '=> 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is essentially just @Brad's answer again, I thought it might be worth including a slightly modified function which will return the index of the item you're searching for if it exists in the array. If the item is not in the array, it returns `-1` instead.

The output of this can be checked just like the "in string" function, `If InStr(...) > 0 Then`, so I made a little test function below it as an example.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsInArrayIndex(stringToFind As String, arr As Variant) As Long

    IsInArrayIndex = -1

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(i) = stringToFind Then
            IsInArrayIndex = i
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

End Function

Sub test()

    Dim fruitArray As Variant
    fruitArray = Array("orange", "apple", "banana", "berry")

    Dim result As Long
    result = IsInArrayIndex("apple", fruitArray)

    If result >= 0 Then
        Debug.Print chr(34) & fruitArray(result) & chr(34) & " exists in array at index " & result
    Else
        Debug.Print "does not exist in array"
    End If

End Sub
```

Then I went a little overboard and fleshed out one for two dimensional arrays because when you [generate an array based on a range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689901/2727437) it's generally in this form.

It returns a single dimension variant array with just two values, the two indices of the array used as an input (assuming the value is found). If the value is not found, it returns an array of `(-1, -1)`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsInArray2DIndex(stringToFind As String, arr As Variant) As Variant

    IsInArray2DIndex= Array(-1, -1)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(i, j) = stringToFind Then
                IsInArray2DIndex= Array(i, j)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Function
```

Here's a picture of the data that I set up for the test, followed by the test:

[image: test 2]

```
Sub test2()

    Dim fruitArray2D As Variant
    fruitArray2D = sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").value

    Dim result As Variant
    result = IsInArray2DIndex("apple", fruitArray2D)

    If result(0) >= 0 And result(1) >= 0 Then
        Debug.Print chr(34) & fruitArray2D(result(0), result(1)) & chr(34) & " exists in array at row: " & result(0) & ", col: " & result(1)
    Else
        Debug.Print "does not exist in array"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to check whether **Examples** exists in Range("A1").Value If it fails then to check **Example** right? I think mycode will work perfect. Please check.

```
Sub test()
Dim string1 As String, string2 As String
string1 = "Examples"
string2 = "Example"
If InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, string1) > 0 Then
    x = 1
ElseIf InStr(1, Range("A1").Value, string2) > 0 Then
    x = 2
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Yes, `Examples` exists in A1 and I can't use strings like you are using, I have an array for my code, otherwise I would have ordinaryly used `InStr`