# If IsInArray(Cells(r, 2), Break_List) = True Then Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-2010

I have been following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba) quite deeply and trying to match `Cell(r,2)` on one sheet to an array I compiled below cycling through rows in column 2 on another sheet but I keep getting a False value returned from the function.

```
    Public Break_List(1 To 1000, 1 To 100) As Variant

    If IsInArray(Cells(r, 2), Break_List) = True Then

    Sub Store_Break_Categories()
    Sheets("BackEnd").Select
    Break_No_of_Rows = 0
    'For c = 10 To 15
    counter = 0
        If Cells(2, 3) <> "" Then
        lastrow = Cells(65000, 3).End(xlUp).Row
           For r = 2 To lastrow
              counter = counter + 1
               'Break_List(counter, c - 9) = Cells(r, c)
                  Break_List(counter, 1) = Cells(r, 3)
           Next r
        End If
        If counter > Break_No_of_Rows Then Break_No_of_Rows = counte
    End Sub
```

This is the function I have integrated from the above question

```
    Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
        IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
    End Function
```

Thank you

Comment: ?? what you've posted isn't valid code.  You'll need to provide sample data and expected results as well, along with what you're currently seeing *instead* of expected results.

Comment: I don't think that function will work on a 2D array. You will have to loop through each each column. You can use Application.Index to shortcut https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/758402-vba-working-with-areas-within-2d-arrays.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application.Match is not going to magically look through 100 columns. If you want to look through the first column then,

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, Application.Index(arr, 0, 1), 0))
End Function
```

If you want to look through all columns then,

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    dim a as long
    IsInArray = false
    for a = lbound(arr, 2) to ubound(arr, 2)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, Application.Index(arr, 0, a), 0)) then
            IsInArray = true
            exit function
        end if
    next a
End Function
```