# Using IF statement to check if the value of a cell or range is contained in an array

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 arrays and a bunch of data.  The arrays are set as ranges...

```
Dim Ar1() As Variant, Ar2() As Variant
Ar2= Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
Ar1= Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value
```

Trying to find something like...

```
If workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").sheets("Sheet1").range("A" & LastRowH).value = Ar1 Then
do an action
Else
do action 2
End If
```

and a second If...Then for Ar2.  This keeps erroring out on me with the Datatype error.  Please let me know if there is a way I can do this.
Thanks!!!!

edit: if I check a range and apply the actions to those that match, then that would be more effecient - Thanks!

Comment: You can use a UDF for this - there are a couple good ones at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for - this UDF returns `True` if the value is found in the array:

```
Sub Test()

If IsInArray(Workbooks("workbook1.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & LastRowH).Value, Ar1) = True Then
    'do something!
Else
    'do something else!
End If

End Sub
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

Comment: The only caveat, which is not a problem for the OP but may be for future readers, is that this will only work for one dimensional arrays.

Comment: If `arr` is a `Range` instead of a `Variant`, then you can use `IsInArray = Not (arr.Find(What:=stringToBeFound, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing)` for 2D ranges

Comment: the above is great.  as a followup, is there a way to vlookup an array and sum the values, or does each datapoint need its own vlookup?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own comment, yes, yes there is.  Found this on the intertube-intranetwork-wifi-google  :D

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?55832-vlookup-array-values