# Excel 2010: How do I formulaically count the total number of cells within a range that containts merged cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been using `=ROWS(my_range)*COLUMNS(my_range)` to count the total number of cells within a single column.

I'm now trying to count the total number of cells across a range that contains (unavoidably) merged cells and I'm getting a `#REF` error using the above formula.

I've also tried: `=COUNTA(my_range) & "/" & COUNTA(my_range) + COUNTBLANK(my_range)` which is giving me a `#VALUE!` error.

In my last attempted I hoped that `=ROWS(my_range)` might work as I've only got merged columns, not merged rows. However this is giving me a `#REF` error. `

All I need is the total number of cells that exists within `my_range`

Thank you

Comment: why the quotes: `& "/" &`  just use `/`

Comment: That gives me a `DIV/0!` error which I've literally never seen before. I didn't know an error could split like that.

Comment: `=COUNTA(my_range) /(COUNTA(my_range) + COUNTBLANK(my_range))`

Comment: Stepping through the evaluation and I'm getting `0/(0+(#VALUE!))` with that which is progress!

Comment: Can't reproduce the error - what is the area that `my_range` refers to?

Comment: A few thousand cells, across columns B & C on a single worksheet, some merged some not and not consistent. It was a nightmare getting them all into `my_range` in the first place. Range definitely works as I use it for bunch of other stuff.

Comment: @L23P What's the actual address? `COUNTBLANK` will return a `#VALUE!` error if `my_range` has more than one area.

Comment: `= COUNTA(range)` will work to count total cells (in a range with merged cells) ***if*** all cells in `range` are not blank. I'm not sure if this is possible to count the number of cells in a range that contain merged cells if some of the cells are blank, because there is no way (that I know of) to distinguish between a merged cell and a blank cell.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 that's why OP is trying to use both `COUNTA` and `COUNTBLANK`. I don't think the point is to distinguish between merged cells and blank cells.

Comment: Would you accept a VBA solution?

Comment: @Pierre44 if the solution could run on launch certainty!  In an annoying workout I've manually entered a 1 into a helper column and used the count function, this isn't ideal but serves.

Answer (score 0):

So using merged cells make it really annoying to work with a lot of formulas, so I wrote a VBA solution using Arrays:

First this function will go through the range and each time it recognizes a merged cell, the code will add the cells to an Array.

Later when the loop comes to a cell marked as "merged" (= is in the array), the count will skip it (thanks to this topic: [Check if a value is in an array or not with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba)).

```
Option Explicit

Function CountCells(RA As Range) As Long

Application.Volatile

    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim i2 As Long
    Dim a2 As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim ColCount As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim R1 As Long
    Dim R2 As Long
    Dim C1 As Long
    Dim C2 As Long
    ReDim iArray(1 To 1) As Variant

R1 = RA.Row
R2 = R1 + RA.Rows.Count - 1
C1 = RA.Column
C2 = C1 + RA.Columns.Count - 1

k = 0

    For i = R1 To R2
        For a = C1 To C2

                If IsInArray(Cells(i, a).Address, iArray) Then
                    GoTo next_a
                End If

            ColCount = Cells(i, a).MergeArea.Columns.Count
            RowCount = Cells(i, a).MergeArea.Rows.Count

                If RowCount > 1 Or ColCount > 1 Then
                    k = k + RowCount * ColCount - 1

                    For i2 = i To i + RowCount - 1
                        For a2 = a To a + ColCount - 1
                            iArray(UBound(iArray)) = Cells(i2, a2).Address
                            ReDim Preserve iArray(1 To UBound(iArray) + 1) As Variant
                       Next a2
                    Next i2

                End If
next_a:
        Next a
    Next i

    CountCells = (R2 + 1 - R1) * (C2 + 1 - C1) - k

End Function


Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
Application.Volatile
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = stringToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Then you just need to use this function like this in your sheet:

```
=countcells(my_range)
```

or any other range instead of your range named my_range

**Note:** With `Application.Volatile` the function updates automatically, but only when you update the sheet with numbers but just not directly when you merge or unmerge cells.

Comment: Thanks @Pierre44 I'll try this now, call me stupid but do I use this in a normal module or does it need to go somewhere else?

Comment: In a normal module from the concerned workbook it is fine :)