# Compile error: ByRef arugment type mismatch: How to call a value in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In a loop, I want to check if value is in an array and if so, then skip to the next iteration.

My low understanding of Arrays are blocking me though:

I am using the function below (from: [Check if a value is in an array or not with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba/38268261#38268261)) to see check whether the value is in the array.

```
Public Function IsInArray(Vtobefound As Long, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i) = Vtobefound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

But my Sub below still doesn't work:

```
Sub CountCellstest()

    Dim i, k As Long
'   Dim iArray() As Single

    ReDim iArray(1 To 1) As Single

    For i = 1 To 3
        If IsInArray(i, iArray) Then 'ERROR HERE on the i

    GoTo next_iteration

        End If

            ReDim aArray(1 To 1) As Single
            iArray(UBound(iArray)) = 2
            ReDim Preserve iArray(1 To UBound(iArray) + 1) As Single
            'DO smth
            MsgBox "test"
next_iteration:
    Next i

End Sub
```

The error comes from the line:

```
If IsInArray(i, iArray) Then
```

I get `Compile error: ByRef arugment type mismatch`
The function IsInArray needs a long and I put a long in the formula so I don't understand the issue... Can someone explain?

Comment: Note that `Dim i, k As Long` only declares `k As Long` but `i As Variant` you must declare a type for **every** variable `Dim i As Long, k As Long`.

Comment: I didn't know this site, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Common mistake. Your `i` variable is actually a `Variant` hence the mismatch. You have to type all the variables individually like this:

```
Dim i As Long, k As Long
```

Comment: Great I wouldn't have seen that. What should I google to understand more about the distinction?

Comment: @Pierre44 Anything about "declaring variables in VBA"

Comment: @Pierre44 Or simply get in the habit of declaring each variable on its own line. It's _much_ easier to spot this type of error that way and, IMHO, much easier to read.