# Lookup value from a cell which has multiple values excel

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have an project billing report downloaded with First Name in column in A and Charge Code in Column B. There are multiple charges codes in one cell which determine whether it is billable or non billable or an erroneous charge code entry.

I am having difficulty using this index match formula as below. Is there a way to lookup value from a cell which has multiple values separated by commas?

`=INDEX(H2:H4,MATCH(H2,B2:B4,0))`

Excel Billing example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer after seeing the sheet layout ... perhaps something like this (with match bug corrected) ...

```
Option Explicit

Public Function LookupCode(ChargeCode As Range, vChargeCodes As Range) As Boolean

    Dim vRow As Long
    Dim vLookupCode As String

    LookupCode = False
    vRow = 2
    Do While LookupCode = False And ActiveSheet.Cells(vRow, 9) <> ""
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(vRow, 9) = ChargeCode Then
            If IsInArray(ActiveSheet.Cells(vRow, 8), Split(vChargeCodes, ",")) Then
                LookupCode = True
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        vRow = vRow + 1
    Loop

End Function

' variation of IsInArray from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim vIndex As Long
    For vIndex = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Trim(arr(vIndex)) = Trim(stringToBeFound) Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```

And then in the sheet...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your list of codes are ALWAYS formatted the same, i.e. first 4 characters are the code, followed by a comma and a space and then the next code you could use "if" and "mid" statements to grab each code

```
=VLOOKUP(MID(B2,1,4),$H$2:$I$4,2,FALSE) & IF(LEN(B2)>5,", " & VLOOKUP(MID(B2,7,4),$H$2:$I$4,2,FALSE),"")
```

Sorry I tend to use vlookup instead of index and match. That formula will work for two codes, repeat the 2nd part of the formula for as many codes as needed.

Goodluck!