# Verify data in cells of a particular column: 25 line limit?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to verify that data in cells of a particular column does not have typos (and/or are in a pre-approved list).

When I tried expanding the range of values to check for 26 or more I get an error. I learned that VBA imposes a limit of 25 lines on certain elements of macros. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/line-too-long

A sample of my code shortened to show what I am trying to achieve. In the real use case, the code is far longer.

Cities that are valid are flagged in green. Anything else is flagged in red.

```vb
Sub checkCities()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A2:A1000")
    For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell Like "New York" Or _
      myCell Like "Chicago" Or _
      myCell Like "Boston" Then

    myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)

    Else: myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 0)

    End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: *"limit of 25 lines on certain elements of macros."* - No, it's a max of 25 lines joined by line continuation characters. Just don't put a single city per line or use a suitable data structure like an array of city names and use a loop to check if `myCell` is `Like` any elements in that array.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I am still a noob to VBA. Could you write a short example of how I should make the code work with arrrays? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba

Comment: You could instead use data validation or a look-up list in a hidden resource worksheet that you can check against.

Comment: I'll give that a try as well. Thanks guys, I have made some progress with this.

Comment: You'd find this easier to mange using a range on a sheet to hold the list - then you can do a (simpler) `Match()` to check each value instead of having the whole list embedded in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In the end, I used Nick's suggestion of adding the values to an array and then checking if the value of each cell was found in the array (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using a `Select Case` instead of an `If/Else`

```
Select Case True
    Case myCell Like "New York"
        myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
    Case myCell Like "Chicago"
        myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
    Case Else
        myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 0)
End Select
```

You should be able to get more than 25 of them then.

You can also combine them like this:

```
Select Case True
    Case myCell Like "New York", myCell Like "Chicago"
        myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
    Case Else
        myCell.Interior.Color = RGB(128, 128, 0)
End Select
```

<sub>I'm not a big fan of line continuations anyway.</sub>

Comment: Excellent! The second of the two suggestions seems like to easiest to digest and thus far (on a small set of 'approved' values) it is working! I"ll test it and see if I can overcome the 25 item 'limit'. :-)

Comment: It can work with a long list of values but not to the degree I was hoping. I'm using the macro to verify the spelling of almost 1000 employees (and not cities). It throws an error, 'procedure too large' but I got around it by adding them to an array instead and then checking if the value each cell in present in the array. It works a beauty. I would still use your solution for shorter lists.