VBA equivalent to in operator
Is there a VBA equivalent to the in operator?
Something that would return FALSE like
5 in [1, 2 , 3, 4]

does in in python or
5 %in% c(1, 2, 3, 4)

does in R?

There is not, you can use a dictionary to get the .contains method, otherwise you have to write your own.

VB is strongly worded. There aren't really one liners like python and R. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267950/check-if-a-value-is-in-an-array-or-not-with-excel-vba

thank you both; I have suspected so... I appreciate your kind comments!

there is no equivalent to "in operator", but you can use something like this:
"|1|2|3|4|" like "*|5|*"
or:
Not IsError(Application.Match(5, array(1,2,3,4), 0))
